# What needs to be done when changing a Bluemix Node.js app name?

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud

I changed the name of a Bluemix Node.js app, but there are some manual actions:

- update of route/URL
- new Devops repo
- update of manifest.yml

Still the GIT URL points to the old URL, which doesn't exist anymore.  Clicking on EDIT CODE leads to this error:

> The project that you specified cannot be found.
>
> The project cannot be found because it was moved, deleted, or does not
>   exist. Verify that the URL is typed correctly and is case sensitive.
>   If you were sent the URL, contact the sender to confirm that it is
>   valid.

Comment: Where did you change the name? GitHub? Bluemix? Toolchain...?

Comment: I renamed it in the Bluemix dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

To change the Git URL associated to your Bluemix application, you can do the following:

Go to your Jazzhub project and click on Build&Deploy. Then you have to configure the stages for build (if needed) and deploy. When configuring the Deploy stage you can specify which Cloud Foundry application is the target of that stage, select the Application name of the Bluemix application that you want to bind (the one with the new name in your case). Then the first time you run the Deploy stage it will bind the Jazzhub project to the (new) Bluemix application. I've just tried and it updated the GIT URL of the renamed application within the Bluemix Dashboard.

Comment: ok, I forgot to mention that I replaced the old app name with the new app name already. I clicked on "run" in deploy and now it works. The last time I deployed the app from the Edit Code page.

Comment: Did you already run a deploy from DevOps Services to Bluemix after doing that?

Comment: Yes, after I changed the manifest I clicked on the arrow in the upper left corner

Comment: Are you doing this in the newly created repo, right? How did you create that repo? It seems strange to me that it has the old Git URL

Comment: I think I just replaced the old repo name in the DevOps settings and with the new name

Comment: Thanks, Umberto. I needed to restart the browser as well, so the little arrow in Devops points to the new URL, but it works now.